# How to indicate that new item was created but is not visible in a list

Tags: lists

In a tasks management app I have a single UI to add new tasks.
Some tasks will end up in a list user can see at the moment and some others will not be seen after being created (since assigned to another user).

[image]

What are some good ways to indicate to the user that new task was created and all is good? Also linking UI video for the case when task belongs to a list and visible right away for reference.

https://youtu.be/cgR9Yl6Hyzg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a simple notification that will pop in and describe the action that was done.

> New task was created
>
> Title: "Buy milk"
>
> Assigned to: Mark P

And after a few seconds the notification will fade away. Or the user can click a close button on the notification.

Also I suggest to have some kind of a log list of all the actions that the user made.
The list can be hidden and toggled on demand.
That way when you create a task that is not visible in your feed you still can track it easily view the log list.

If you know trello.com , then you should check how they implemented their log list.

Comment: Will check Trello for this, thanks. Definitely have toaster notifications in mind as a last resort but was hoping to come up with something more appealing

Comment: A toaster can be designed to look appealing ;)

Comment: Jira does this as well when you add a new issue that doesn't match the filter criteria for the board or search page you are on. It says something like "Created issue [link]. It is not visible because it ..."

Answer (score 1):

Some ways I would approach this is using maybe the same motion UI you are using where the user is known to see the list come in, but since it's being assigned to someone else, maybe it turns a different BG color and shows being "Assigned to X" while fades away almost like a successful popup modal without being too distracting and leaving eye-focus area?

Maybe explain a scenario more in-depth and I'd love to provide some more options.

Another case would be if the user who isn't assigning themselves or to someone else that won't be seeing it initially, there is your user profile on top right...Maybe a (1) notification to show what it's assigned to or X was now listed so you have a notifications pop-up?

Comment: Interesting idea. Thinking now on having some special section on top of list for these "recently updated" or alike tasks